# Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000

Tags: java, maven, sockets, debugging, port

[image]

I have the above debug config . The port  i have given is 8050, but when i give the command in terminal it runs as 8000. How can i change the dt_socket port.

[image]

Comment: what's library you're using?

Comment: “Give the command in terminal” means what exactly?

Comment: the command mvnDebug.

Comment: Which library ?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you use `mvnDebug ...` command.

Port 8000 is default for `mvnDebug`, if you want to debug Maven process please simply set in your editor the same port - 8000.

Maybe you want achieve something else - it is not clear from question.

For changing default debug port for `mvnDebug` you can use `MAVEN_DEBUG_ADDRESS` environment variable.

eg.

```
MAVEN_DEBUG_ADDRESS=8050 mvnDebug ...
```

Comment: 8000 port is already used by another server in my project so i had  to change port from 8000 to 8050.Now when i try to debug it tries to listen dt_socket to 8000 and waits there forever . How can i change that to 8050. Is there any solution?answer is highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes the command is mvnDebug ...